Import Active Directory PowerShell Module inside a Python project
I have a python file contains a PowerShell script using subprocess library. So I import Active Directory module inside my PowerShell script, But it needs the module to be loaded and exists in my pc but after I build python file to be an exe file, and run the exe on another pc which doesn't have the module installed it didn't return data.
So how can I include the module correctly inside my python project ?
I tried to copy "ActiveDirectory" folder from this path "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules" but with nothing new.

Might depend on the specific AD module dependent commands you are running to determine the best solution if this is possible. Might be ways around each command without using the AD module but hard to tell without knowing what pertinent logic you are working it. Otherwise, just trivial for research and testing to confirm.
